# WordPress - Google Map API label / Progress Map + BuddyPress Member count

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Basically, I would like to add Label on my map Marker which returns the count of my [BuddyPress](https://buddypress.org/) Members per location (just a number like MarkerClusterer is producing) and when I then when I click on it redirect to a specific Url.

Also, I would like to tweak the [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) number to add these numbers together, instead of counting the number of Markers I have inside.

**The problem**: I am struggling on trying to tweak the functionalities included in the plugin [Progress Map](https://codecanyon.net/item/progress-map-wordpress-plugin/5581719) and the developer of this one apparently doesn't bother to dirty his hands.

Anyway, this is the kind of **result** I would like (the **white labels** in the red spots):

[image]

I found the way to **retrieve the count of my members per location** with the following code:

```
                        <?php global $bp;
                        if ( bp_has_members( bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ). '&per_page='.sq_option('buddypress_perpage') ) ) :
                            $region = array();
                            while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member();
                                $region[] = xprofile_get_field_data( 'Region' , bp_get_member_user_id() );//fetch the text for location
                            endwhile;
                        endif; ?>
                        /* print_r(array_count_values(array_map('strtolower', $region))); */
```

Here is the **call to create the object marker**:

```
                                /**
                             * Create the pin object */

                            var marker_object = cspm_new_pin_object(<?php echo $l; ?>, '<?php echo $post_id; ?>', <?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lng; ?>, '<?php echo $implode_post_categories; ?>', map_id, '<?php echo $marker_img_by_cat; ?>', '<?php echo $marker_img_size; ?>', '<?php echo $is_child; ?>');
                            json_markers_data.push(marker_object);
```

And here **the function cpsm_new_pin_object** (I guess this is where Google Maps API is used):

```
    function cspm_new_pin_object(i, post_id, lat, lng, post_categories, map_id, marker_img, marker_size, is_child){

    /**
     * [@map_script_id] | Used only to get map options from the PHP option wp_localize_script()
     * @since 3.0 */
    var map_script_id = (typeof progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_id] !== 'undefined') ? map_id : 'initial';

    post_lat_lng_coords[map_id][post_id] = lat+'_'+lng;

    // Create an object of that post_id and its categories/status for the faceted search
    post_lat_lng_coords[map_id]['post_id_'+post_id] = {};
    post_ids_and_child_status[map_id][lat+'_'+lng] = is_child;

    // Get the current post categories  
    var post_category_ids = (post_categories != '') ? post_categories.split(',') : '';

    // Collect an object of all posts in the map and their categories
    // Useful for the faceted search & the search form
    post_lat_lng_coords[map_id]['post_id_'+post_id][0] = post_category_ids;

    // By default the marker image is the default Google map red marker
    var marker_icon = '';

    // If the selected marker is the customized type
    if(progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['defaultMarker'] == 'customize'){

        // Get the custom marker image
        // If the marker categories option is set to TRUE, the marker image will be the uploaded marker category image
        // If the marker categories option is set to FALSE, the marker image will be the default custom image provided by the plugin
        var marker_cat_img = marker_img;

        // Marker image size
        var marker_img_width = (progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['retinaSupport'] == "true") ? parseInt(marker_size.split('x')[0])/2 : parseInt(marker_size.split('x')[0]);
        var marker_img_height = (progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['retinaSupport'] == "true") ? parseInt(marker_size.split('x')[1])/2 : parseInt(marker_size.split('x')[1]);

        // Marker image anchor point
        var anchor_y = marker_img_height/2;
        var anchor_x = marker_img_width/2;  
        var anchor_point = null;

        if(progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['marker_anchor_point_option'] == 'auto')                
            anchor_point = new google.maps.Point(anchor_x, anchor_y);
        else if(progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['marker_anchor_point_option'] == 'manual'){
            if(progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['retinaSupport'] == "true"){
                anchor_point = new google.maps.Point(
                    progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['marker_anchor_point'].split(',')[0]/2, 
                    progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['marker_anchor_point'].split(',')[1]/2
                );
            }else anchor_point = new google.maps.Point(progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['marker_anchor_point'].split(',')[0], progress_map_vars.map_script_args[map_script_id]['marker_anchor_point'].split(',')[1]);
        }

        // Add retina support
        marker_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker_cat_img, null, null, anchor_point, new google.maps.Size(marker_img_width,marker_img_height));                  

    }       

    return pin_object = {latLng: [lat, lng], tag: 'post_id__'+post_id, id: post_id+'_'+is_child, options:{ optimized: false, icon: marker_icon, id: post_id, post_id: post_id, is_child: is_child }};                                       

}
```

Coming of course in his **minify version**:

```
cspm_new_pin_object(e,s,a,r,t,i,o,_,p){var n="undefined"!=typeof progress_map_vars.map_script_args[i]?i:"initial";post_lat_lng_coords[i][s]=a+"_"+r,post_lat_lng_coords[i]["post_id_"+s]={},post_ids_and_child_status[i][a+"_"+r]=p;var c=""!=t?t.split(","):"";post_lat_lng_coords[i]["post_id_"+s][0]=c;var m="";if("customize"==progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].defaultMarker){var l=o,d="true"==progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].retinaSupport?parseInt(_.split("x")[0])/2:parseInt(_.split("x")[0]),u="true"==progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].retinaSupport?parseInt(_.split("x")[1])/2:parseInt(_.split("x")[1]),g=u/2,f=d/2,v=null;"auto"==progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].marker_anchor_point_option?v=new google.maps.Point(f,g):"manual"==progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].marker_anchor_point_option&&(v="true"==progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].retinaSupport?new google.maps.Point(progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].marker_anchor_point.split(",")[0]/2,progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].marker_anchor_point.split(",")[1]/2):new google.maps.Point(progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].marker_anchor_point.split(",")[0],progress_map_vars.map_script_args[n].marker_anchor_point.split(",")[1])),m=new google.maps.MarkerImage(l,null,null,v,new google.maps.Size(d,u))}return pin_object={latLng:[a,r],label:'B',tag:"post_id__"+s,id:s+"_"+p,options:{optimized:!1,icon:m,id:s,post_id:s,is_child:p}}}
```

**To summarize**, 2 or 3 things here:

- Be able to insert a label (counter) inside my red dots (markers)
- Tweak of the [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) plugin to display the total of the other counters (dynamically if we unzoom) instead of the count of markers inside it.
- (additional) add a custom link with a (?) symbol inside a WP "Post" (but I should be able to do it with [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)).

Map Source: https://spanishblackgarlic.com/spanishblackgarlic/

Answer (score 2):

Well it's gonna be hard for you to have help as you're not using google maps api directly. I don't know how it works with wordpress so i can't help modifying the actual code... but i think you can overpass some things.

1) for the labelled marker, do you have a "max" users ? You can use a custom image for the marker What you can do is having 1 image marker for each number... unless you have too much. If yes, you can use an automatic generated image, like mysite.com/genMarker.php?number=98. Not the hardest thing to do with php.

2) for the markercluster there too, you can probably modify markerclusterer, but i can suggest another way :
- You continue to add your "grouped" markers with custom labels (1 marker for 10 users), but you don't push them to markerclusterer
- You add 1 marker for each user (ie 10 markers at same place if you have 10 users)... with a transparent image marker : you add them to your clusterer

Then you should have the correct behavior for clusters, without having to modify the core of it.

I don't know if you have possibility to chosse yes or not to add a marker to cluster... but this is a way a bit easier. I know it's ugly but i think it could work ;)

Comment: Hi Pierre. Thanks for your interest! 
Unfortunately, your solutions are not dynamic at all and pretty bad in terms of development. I was thinking the same for the markers but it's also silly for the maintenance etc. 
However I am pretty sure this plugin is coded with Google API v3, so using PHP to call the map, Wordpress is not changing the behavior, just calling the API then using it through a function.
I was also thinking to a JS solution, but I can't figure out how to Select my "Markers images". If I could do it, I guess it's a pretty easy fix with JS.

Comment: Pierre, any idea?